# Horizontal alignment of divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design something like this on a page:

[image]

Basically, I need to make sure the four columns are centered and are aligned on the top (vertically). I was able to achieve this using the following CSS:

```
.parent
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.child
{
    max-width: 220px;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <h3>The Problem</h3>
        <p>Reliance on fossil fuels face many challenges:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>They have a negative impact on the environment</li>
            <li>Availability and pricing is influenced by foreign interests and stability</li>
            <li>Resources are becoming more scarce and more costly to extract</li>
            <li>Their cost increases each year</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
        <h3>The Promise</h3>
        <p>Solar energy offers a powerful promise:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Inexhaustable supply</li>
            <li>Worldwide availability</li>
            <li>Environmentally clean &#8211; lowest impact to the environment</li>
            <li>Creates jobs in the U.S.</li>
            <li>Cost that will be competitive with traditional generation technologies</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
        <h3>The Purpose</h3>
        <p>To develop sustainable environmentally and socially responsible energy solutions:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Deliver the highest efficiency solar conversion</li>
            <li>Utilize low cost recyclable materials</li>
            <li>Provide cost effective installations for rooftop and ground mount</li>
            <li>Suitable for commercial, utility, and residential applications</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
        <h3>The People</h3>
        <p>People are our most important asset:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Highly skilled and creative staff with over 100 patents</li>
            <li>Leadership team with proven experience  building industry changing businesses</li>
            <li>Committed to making a contribution every day to our customers, community, coworkers and investors</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this is what it looks like when I render it:

[image]

The problem is; the text is also **horizontally centered inside the child divs**. Is there a way to prevent this? I'm unable to find a "horizontal-align" property which would probably help.

Comment: `text-align:left` on `.child` : http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/S2fhL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.child
{
max-width: 220px;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;
margin: 30px;
vertical-align: top;
text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.child p{
 text-align: left;

}

.child ul li{

text-align: left;

}
```

Comment, if it works or not

Comment: It did work. Someone else answered before you though. Thanks anyways!

Comment: fine :D, happy coding @PoweredByOrange

Answer (score 1):

All the text is centered because you are using `text-align:center;` on parent element.

If you need to reconfigure the `text-align`; you have to add the `text-align:left;` or `text-align:right;` to move the text on left or on right.

Here in your case you have to  add `text-align:left` on your class `.child`.

```
.child
{
    text-align:left; /*This line need to add*/
    max-width: 220px;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was the Inheritance, If a higher Tag has an Attribut like **text-align: center**  all lower classes will take the same settings.

So if you wanna change this, you have to overwrite it to **text-align: left** like
*Suresh Ponnukalai* said.

```
.child
{
max-width: 220px;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;
margin: 30px;
vertical-align: top;
text-align:left;
}
```